# Is it possible to show data when hovering over an item with qgis2web (OL3)?

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis2web

I'm using the qgis2web plugin and I want to show the records behind the different items on the map when I am hovering over them. Is that possible when you have layers devided into groups? And my output file needs to be Openlayers 3 type.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top item you highlight is a layer. The bottom one is a group. I don't believe layer grouping works very well yet in qgis2web. Popups on hover should work in non-grouped layers, though.

Comment: Thanks again for the information Chadwin. But in qgis2leaf the layer grouping doesn't work so the only way to do this is by coding it myself?

Comment: Until we get groups working properly in qgis2web, yes. UPDATE: issue raised https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/175